# ¿como puedo comparar los registros de un arreglo y comparar con el que esta logeado actualmente?

Tags: angular, ionic

estoy trabajando en un proyecto de ionic y angular para realizar y contestar encuestas, el problema es que los usuarios no deben poder contestar la misma encuesta dos veces para eso hice que se almacene su usuario junto las respuestas y hago una comparación con el usuario actual con el que ya este almacenado en las respuestas el problema es que no logro traer el especifico una vez hecha la consulta agradeceré sus orientaciones y ayuda gracias.

Comment: Puedes mostrar código?

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que las encuestas están guardadas por ahí, en ese mismo por ahí que guardas las encuestas me imagino que estás guardando los usuarios, por lo general deberian ser tablas sql o algo no sql, el tema es que deberias tener un id para cada usuario y en una tercera tabla (en caso de ser relacional) llamemosla encuestas-usuario, esa deberia tener llave foranea del usuario y de las encuestas que han sido respondidas, con esto solamente haces una query y te traes las encuestas que no tengan relacion con ese usuario e la tabla encuestas usuario:

tabla usuario:
id
nombre

tabla encuestas:
id
nombre

tabla encuestas-usuario
id_usuario
id_encuesta

y a esa le haces las querys: